# Script started with nohup get killed when leave terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, nohup

I need to run some python scripts with infinite loop on ubuntu server (Amazon EC2). And I really like the idea to use nohup as it is simple and I can have output.out log file. I start script like

```
nohup script.py > output.out &
```

The process get started. I check it with jobs -l all fine. 
Then I close the terminal and log back check processes with jobs -l and I can't see it any more. Can you advise me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you change session (log out and come back), there is no chance you'll see your script as job.

try `ps` instead.

```
ps -u myuser
```

replacing myuser with actual login..

Answer (score 0):

If your job is visible when you use `jobs -l` you can remove it from your session with `disown`

Another way to keep script running is to use the `screen` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting all I/O streams

```
nohup script.py < /dev/null > output.out 2> error.out &
```

Answer (score 0):

**Long expalation**:
Background running process (job) is always bound to particular terminal:

```
[11]user@lab7-11:~> nohup ./test.sh > out &
[1] 39978

[11]user@lab7-11:~> ps aux |grep 39978
user   39978  0.0  0.0 106096  1156 pts/11   S    06:15   0:00 bash ./test.sh
```

While it is bound to terminal, you are able to see it in `jobs` output:

```
[11]user@lab7-11:~> jobs -l
[1]+ 39978 Running                 nohup ./test.sh > out &
```

After you've closed that terminal, your **job** became **daemon** and is not more bound to terminal

```
[7]user@lab7-11:~> ps aux |grep 39978
user   39978  0.0  0.0 106096  1156 ?        S    06:15   0:00 bash ./test.sh
```

So, at this stage, you can check state of your process via `ps` as suggested by @Archemar but not via `job`

**Short explanation:**
Your script was **not** killed - it became daemon.

Comment: Thanks. With ps I can see that process is still running. Thanks a lot

Comment: If this helped, you can accept this as answer  :)